# What's an alternative term for a "dry lake"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I need to succinctly and more-or-less poetically describe a dry lake. As in, a lake that is no longer a lake proper, cuz it is no longer full of water. "It was at the bottom of a dry lake."

Problem is that it's raining heavily, and this not-a-lake is muddy, not dry. Little details like that really bug me! What's the most to-the-point term I can use that's stylistically right for dramatic prose?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_lake.

Comment: Former lakes -- usually deep underground -- are extremely important paleolontological sources for past climate and biological details. While a lake is present, it records the pollen and other evidence, every year, separated by seasons. Lakes often last centuries, which is a nice overlapping record, like tree rings; there have been a **lot** of lakes over the past millions of years. Oh, and they're all dry, naturally, so they're just called "lakes".

Comment: You're describing an [ephemeral lake](https://www.oceanscape-aquarium.org/ephemeral-lakes.html)

Comment: You could perhaps call it a "lakebed" or "basin". If it sometimes fills with rain (as you suggest), then it could be a "floodplain".

Comment: There's also *seasonal lake* or *intermittent lake*, generally for places that are lakes in the wet season but not in the dry season.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the dried lakes found in desert basins (_playas_). 'Intermittent lake' seems the most idiomatic strong collocation (or arguably compound noun).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lakebed), the *lakebed* suggested in a comment should work:

> The bottom of a lake, especially after the lake has gone dry. Usage notes: Though the word lakebed itself typically implies that the lake has gone dry, the phrase *dry lakebed* is frequently used for additional clarity.

If you want to talk about the muddy state, that could be clarified too.  I can't suggest anything specific because I don't know the particulars, e.g., why is it no longer a proper lake, what the amount of water or moisture is in the various seasons, and whether there are any streams that feed in or out.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use **bog** (or swamp or marsh or other synonyms like quagmire which may subjectively sound more poetic, perhaps).

Google dictionary (Google search for "define bog"):

> ***bog***
> *noun*
>
> 1. an area of wet muddy ground that is too soft to support a heavy body. "a peat bog"

To perhaps paraphrase part of your question, and as an intended pun, you could perhaps say, "Little details like that really ***bog** me down*."